# Which camera to connect with Raspberry pi2

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

Using a compatible usb webcam or pi cam. Which of these two is better in the way of controlling the capture settings like iso, exposure time, etc ? And which of these will be more energy efficient and easier to integrate with pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raspi camera connects directly to the GPU, and is capable of 1080p30 video encode, 5MP stills in pretty decent quality. Because its attached to the GPU, there is only a little impact on the CPU, leaving it available for other processing.

Webcams (unless they have built in encoding - expensive) are unlikely to get the same performance, and they also use a LOT more CPU.

The difference between the Pi Camera and USB webcam is performance and higher frame rate with h.264 video encoding.
With a USB webcam you have low frame rate and no GPU encoding but that doesn't really matter if all you want to do is take photos.